# Beautifulsoup problem getting grandparent and li childs

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

This is my html:

```
html = """<ul id="mostUp">
   <li class="Upper"> ‹
      <a href="x">Countries</a>
   </li>
   <ul>
      <li> 
         <span class="country_selection">Germany</span>
      </li>
      <ul>
         <li><a href="x">Frankfurt</a></li>
         <li><a href="x">München</a></li>
      </ul>
   </ul>
</ul>
"""
```

Cause `country_selection` is the only unique element which i can select, i am now trying to get the `LI`'s with the Cities (Frankfurt and München).

This is my code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
categories = soup.find("span", class_="country_selection")

if categories.parent.parent.find("ul"):
  e = categories.parent.parent.select('ul')
  for subItem in e:
    print(subItem)
```

But this gives me this result:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="x">Frankfurt</a></li>
  <li><a href="x">München</a></li>
</ul>
```

So, this means, that i have the Parent UL and cannot iterate through the LIs. And i don't know why! Where is the error? How do i need to change my code to iterate through those LIs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get `Frankfurt` and `München`, you can go this way:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<ul id="mostUp">
   <li class="Upper"> ‹
      <a href="x">Countries</a>
   </li>
   <ul>
      <li>
         <span class="country_selection">Germany</span>
      </li>
      <ul>
         <li><a href="x">Frankfurt</a></li>
         <li><a href="x">München</a></li>
      </ul>
   </ul>
</ul>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
categories = soup.find("span", class_="country_selection")

if categories.parent.parent.find("ul"):
  e = categories.parent.parent.select('ul a')
  for subItem in e:
    print(subItem.text)
```

Prints:

```
Frankfurt
München
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a parent or for loop! You can get `Frankfurt` and `München` by this way:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
categories = soup.find("span", class_="country_selection")

data = categories.findNext("ul").text.strip().split()
```